# Android arraylist<String> to single string

Tags: java, android, twitter, arraylist

I have an     `ArrayList<String> statusListTextOnly;` that contains some tweets.
If I use it with listview it will work fine, but I want to use it for another thing.

I tried:

```
    Tweet weather_data[] = new Tweet[] {
        new Tweet(statusListTextOnly)
    };
```

But I get error from it `The constructor Tweet(ArrayList<String>) is undefined`

**My Tweet class:**

```
public class Tweet {
    public ArrayList<String> title;

    public Tweet(){
        super();
    }

    public Tweet(ArrayList<String> title) {
        super();
        for(String s : title)
        this.title = s;
    }
}
```

currently I get error from **s** `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ArrayList<String>`

Comment: If you didn't understand my question tell me please

Comment: Sidenote: Always use 'List' instead of 'ArrayList' as formal parameters, fields etc. The only point where you should use the concrete class ArrayList is when you're creating it (with 'new').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the error is very clear.

```
this.title = s;
```

There `title` is of type `ArrayList` and you are assigning String `s`.

Change

```
 public ArrayList<String> title;
```

to

```
 public String title;
```

It does'nt make sense that `title` is a `list` normally. It should be a `String`.

If you still want it as a `List`

then , simply assign it to your list.

```
public Tweet(ArrayList<String> title) {
        super();      
        this.title = title;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, ill post another question regarding my other issue

Comment: please check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162764/android-set-arraylist-data-to-custom-adapter .. Accepted :D