# Android set Arraylist data to custom adapter

Tags: java, android, twitter, arraylist

I have an     `ArrayList<String> statusListTextOnly;` that contains some tweets.
Now if I use it like this

```
i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusListTextOnly));
```

Everything is fine, the activity starts and the tweets show in listview.

**But** I wanted to go deep in my app, I want to use custom adapter.

So I did:

```
Tweet[] tweets;
TweetAdapter adapter;

    Tweet weather_data[] = new Tweet[] {
        new Tweet(statusListTextOnly)
    };

    adapter = new TweetAdapter(MainAcitivity.this,
            R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);

    i.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**My Tweet clasS:**

```
public class Tweet {
     public String title;

    public Tweet(){
        super();
    }

    public Tweet(ArrayList<String> title) {
        super();
        for(String s : title)
        this.title = s;
    }
}
```

**My TweetAdapter class:**

```
public class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Tweet data[] = null;

    public TweetAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Tweet[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        TweetHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new TweetHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (TweetHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Tweet tweet = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(tweet.title);

        return row;
    }

    static class TweetHolder
    {
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}
```

Now when I run it, only one tweet shows up (The last tweet). It's fine but the `listview` has only one item, only one tweet shows up not whole tweets list.

**ex.** `statusListTextOnly` contain:

```
1,
2,
3.
5,
6,
7
```

it only shows `7` in the `listview`.

Comment: pass MainActivity.this insted of getBaseContext()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Tweet(ArrayList<String> title) {
    super();
    for(String s : title)
    this.title = s;
}
```

Every time you override your title value, so you see only the last value from ArrayList of titles. Change your logic in this constructor to some kind of this:

```
public Tweet(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

And then do:

```
List<Tweet> tweets = new ArratList<Tweet>();
for (String s: statusListTextOnly)
    tweets.add(new Tweet(s))
```

and put the `tweets` to your ArrayAdapter, don't forget to change Tweet[] to List in adapter ;)
Good luck !

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from this line in Tweet class :

```
for(String s : title)
    this.title = s;
```

What do you wanna do exactly here ? I can't say, but you take the last title in the list.